# Convert PNG frames to video with missing frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, framerate

I have a camera that records at 30 FPS. I have found that the camera drops frames sometimes.

What I have are PNG files named `_Color_<some_number>.png`. For example, `_Color_1.png to _Color_10000.png`, but with missing files in between.

**How can I best use FFmpeg to convert these PNG frames to video?** If I use 30 FPS as the framerate, then the video appears a little fast since there are missing frames.

Is it possible to use FFmpeg to make a video, duplicating frames to fill in what is missing? Is it possible to use a variable frame rate? Would these yield the same results?

Comment: ATSC and NTSC video actually makes 29.97 frames per second. How many frames are you missing per hour?

Comment: @K7AAY A significant amount -- about half...

It varies between the files I have, I am still analyzing how many frames are dropped, so I am not sure, but it is definitely a significant amount

It's possible that the frames appear dropped because my original recording files (in this case they are BAG files from a RealSense Intel camera) are compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options. One: write a small shell script that copies the preceding frames to the missing positions based on the numbers. That is:

- Iterate from 1 to 10000
- If you can't find a frame at the given index, copy the file with the highest preceding index.
- Use the classic way to [create a slideshow](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow#Sequential). The result could however be quite jerky depending on how many frames are missing, because many frames will be duplicated.

Another method would be to create a variable framerate video from the images. A method is shown in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893746/435093). Basically, you need to:

- Sanitize the file names such that the index numbers are sequential
- Create a constant framerate video
- Generate a timestamp metadata file based on the original index numbers multiplied by the assumed framerate
- Convert the constant framerate video to a variable framerate one
- Optionally, for maximum compatibility: convert the VFR video back to CFR, perhaps using the `minterpolate` filter to add motion smoothing